# Lower Bounds and Greatest Lower Bounds

Tags: relations

Let (a, b),(x, y) ∈ R × R and deﬁne ≺ as follows:

(a, b) ≺ (c, d) iﬀ

a < c or a = c and b < d:

Deﬁne (a, b) ≼ (c, d) if and only if (a, b) = (c, d) or (a, b) ≺ (c, d).

Show that there is a subset of R  R that has a lower bound but
no greatest lower bound.

Let S = {(x, y) ∈ (Q+)x (Z+) | P ∈ irrationals and Z ∈ positive integers {x > 1, y = 1}

Claim: (0, 0) is a lower bound for S because 0 < x because x ∈ P+.

Thus (0, 0) ≼ (x, y) by the given order.

Assume that (b, 1) is the greatest lower bound for S.

I know I need to prove there is no greatest lower bound in the set, but I'm not sure how to. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, note that a point $(x,y)$ will be a lower bound if and only if $x\leq 1$ (why?).

With that in mind, suppose that $(x,y)$ is a lower bound.  What can we say about $(x,y+1)$?

For future reference, this way of ordering a set of numbers is called [Lexicographical order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).

Comment: I would say that it would also be a lower bound, because the set is infinite and there is always a number related that is larger. Thus, the set doesn't have a greatest lower bound because each number in the set is a lower bound.     I'm not sure if these thoughts are accurate though.

Comment: You're right about the conclusion, but I don't understand your explanation for how you know that $(x,y+1)$ is also a lower-bound.